# Shifting Values in R in rows

Tags: r

I have a problem that sounds easy, however, I could not find a solution in R. I would like to shift values according to the first year of the release. I mean the first column represents the years of the release and the columns are years when the device is broken (values are numbers of broken devices).

This is a solution in Python:

```
def f(x):
    shifted = np.argmin((x.index.astype(int)< x.name[0]))
    return x.shift(-shifted)

df = df.set_index(['Delivery Year', 'Freq']).apply(f, axis=1)
df.columns = [f'Year.{i + 1}' for i in range(len(df.columns))]
df = df.reset_index()
df
```

I would like to have it in R too.

```
# TEST
data <- data.frame(
  `Delivery Year` = c('1976','1977','1978','1979'),
  `Freq` = c(120,100,80,60),
  `Year.1976` = c(10,NA,NA,NA),
  `Year.1977` = c(5,3,NA,NA),
  `Year.1978` = c(10,NA,8,NA),
  `Year.1979` = c(13,10,5,14)
)

data

# DESIRED
data <- data.frame(
  `Delivery Year` = c('1976','1977','1978','1979'),
  `Freq` = c(120,100,80,60),
  `Year.1` = c(10,3,8,14),
  `Year.2` = c(5,NA,5,NA),
  `Year.3` = c(10,10,NA,NA),
  `Year.4` = c(13,NA,NA,NA)
)

data
```

[image]

In addition, would it be also possible to transform the number of broken devices into the percentage of Freq column?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`

```
data %>% 
pivot_longer(!c(Delivery.Year, Freq)) %>% 
separate(name, c("Lab", "Year")) %>% 
select(-Lab) %>% 
mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% 
filter(Year >= Delivery.Year) %>% 
group_by(Delivery.Year, Freq) %>% 
mutate(ind = paste0("Year.", row_number()), 
       per = value/Freq) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Delivery.Year, Freq), names_from = ind, values_from = c(value, per))
```

I pivoted it into long form to begin with and separated the original column names `Year.1976`, `Year.1977`, etc. to just get the years from the columns and dropped the `Year` piece of it. Then I converted all columns to `numeric` to allow for mathematical operations like filtering for when `Year >= Delivery.Year`. I then created a column to get the titles you did request `Year.1`, `Year.2`, etc. and calculated the percent. Then I `pivot_wider` to get it in the format you requested. One thing to note is that I was unclear if you wanted both the original values and the percent or just the percent. If you only want the percent then `values_from = per` should do it for you.

Comment: Where I change the code to get percentage table only? Thank you :)

Comment: In `pivot_wider`, use `values_from = per` should get you only the percents

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(df) {
  years <-  paste0("Year.",sort(as.vector(na.omit(as.integer(stringr::str_extract(colnames(df), "\\d+"))))))
  df1 <- df %>% select(years) 
  df2 <- df %>% select(-years) 
  val <- c()
  
  firstyear <- years[1]
  for (k in 1:nrow(df1) ) {
      vec <- as.numeric(as.vector(df1[k,]))
      val[k] <- (as.numeric(suppressWarnings(na.omit(vec))))[1]
  }
  df1[firstyear] <- val
  colnames(df1) <- c(paste0("Year.",seq(1:ncol(df1))))
  df <- cbind(df2,df1)
  
  print(df)
  
}

> f(data)
  Delivery.Year Freq Year.1 Year.2 Year.3 Year.4
1          1976  120     10      5     10     13
2          1977  100      3      3     NA     10
3          1978   80      8     NA      8      5
4          1979   60     14     NA     NA     14
```